# PHTML PHP coding doesn't work with button

Tags: php, html

I use a PHP coding included with HTML. My code is:

The thing is that even though the code is perfect, whenever I press on the button, nothing in the page happens. No output is received, of any error or success and the page remains as it is. I tried it with a simple code to echo "Success" and even then, the page remained as it is.

Can anyone help out?

```
<html>

<header>
<title>View Table!</title>
</header>

<body>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_view'])) {

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection not established!");
}

$tablename = $_POST['table_name'];

$sql = "SELECT emp_name,emp_address,emp_salary,emp_joindate FROM employee";
mysqli_select_db($conn, "hello");

$retval = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$retval) {
    echo ("Error in SQL") . mysqli_error();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($retval)) {
    echo "Employee name: {$row['emp_name']}" .
        "Employee address: {$row['emp_address']}" .
        "Employee Salary: {$row['emp_salary']}" .
        "Employee Joindate: {$row['emp_joindare']}".
        "<br />";
}

echo("All queries done!");
mysqli_close($conn);



}

else {
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table><tr><td>Enter Table Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="table_name" id="table_name"></td>

        </tr>

        <tr><td><input type="button" name="button_view" id = "button_view" value="View Table!" /></td></tr></table>

</form>

<?php
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try with `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`.

Comment: I did so. I used submit instead of button and made all the other changes as you said. Now whenever I click on the submit button in the page, the page redirects me to a 404 Not found URL. The original URL of the PHP is: `"http://localhost:63342/htdocs/PHPStorm/Project%201/new%20one.php?_ijt=er6eh7uq9rd6umtfmru0et61ov"`.  Now whenever I click on the submit button, the page takes me to `http://localhost:63342/htdocs/PHPStorm/Project%201/new%20one.php` URL and shows a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mistakes in that code.

1. Use `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`, as Syscall said.
2. Remove spaces between `id` and `"button_view"`.
3. Replace the `<header>` tag with `<head>`
4. Instead of `$_PHP_SELF`, use `echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`
5. `mysqli_error()` needs a parameter. Use `$conn` as parameter.

Comment: I did so. I used submit instead of button and made all the other changes as you said. Now whenever I click on the submit button in the page, the page redirects me to a 404 Not found URL. The original URL of the PHP is: `"http://localhost:63342/htdocs/PHPStorm/Project%201/new%20one.php?_ijt=er6eh7uq9rd6umtfmru0et61ov"`.  Now whenever I click on the submit button, the page takes me to `http://localhost:63342/htdocs/PHPStorm/Project%201/new%20one.php` URL and shows a 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The web server for PHPStorm wasn't deployed, thank you for help.